# Meme blocker for Google Chrome

Tags: windows-7, chrome, productivity, ad-blocker

I am looking for a Google Chrome extension that can block meme pictures.

[Examples](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/02/why-stack-overflow-doesnt-care-about-ad-blockers/?cb=1):

[image]

[image]

[image]

It should work with Windows 7, if OS-dependent. Gratis is better.

Comment: A typical ad-blocker (uBlock Origin is best, ABP is best for platforms uBO doesn't support) can subscribe to custom filter-lists, and one could be made up to try to catch common meme pictures. What's harder to do is to programmatically determine which pictures are memes, and such a thing would be too burdensome on your browsing experience.

Comment: Related: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/7052/database-or-api-to-quickly-check-whether-an-image-is-a-meme-or-not

Comment: Kill is kiss. Kill is kiss. Kill is kiss.

Comment: lazy option: blacklist most likely offending sites...4chan, imgur, etc. you'll lose a lot of non-meme content on each site, but that sounds much, much easier to implement. very interested to see programmatic solutions sprinkled with regex. or something i can't even comprehend.  i originally posted this on open data

Comment: Find a way to detect when an image contains the Impact font. That ought to block most of them.

Answer (score 2):

The difficulty with a meme blocker is that it's [hard to identify which images are memes](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/7052/database-or-api-to-quickly-check-whether-an-image-is-a-meme-or-not) and which are non-meme kitten pictures. Probably your best bet is to use a text-only browser mode. On Chrome, [Text Mode](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/text-mode/adelhekhakakocomdfejiipdnaadiiib) seems a good choice:

[image: Text Mode]

In my test, it does block those images on [the blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/02/why-stack-overflow-doesnt-care-about-ad-blockers/). It doesn't put a red X over them, but it does allow several options for replacing images:

[image: Text Mode options]

Unfortunately, as I alluded to, it doesn't target memes, but all sorts of images including the site logo, the author avatar, and other potentially informative images. But on the internet, nearly any image is a potential meme so think of this as future-proofing.

The extension toggles the text-only mode for new page loads. It does not re-render pages loaded with images. It also does not reflow text, but leaves the textblock shaped as if the image still existed. Fortunately, this extension does work with [Readability](https://www.readability.com/) to produce a pleasing page sans images.